# Windows 10 Professional: Doesn't Boot after Power Outage

Tags: windows, boot, power

I have a Windows 10 Pro tower (Lenovo ThinkServer 440) which has two SSD drives setup as Raid 1 (mirror). The computer is super fast and stable! Except when there is a power outage. And here is something very strange: After a power outage, when the computer boots, the screen shows 'Out of Range' and goes on rebooting. Only thing odd *appears* is that Lenovo's screen shows the Raid volume as 'Verify'.

So I insert a Windows 10 64 bit System Repair Disk, choose 'Boot from CD', select English as the language, and in next screen choose something like 'Continue with Windows'. And, voila! Next time the computer boots into Windows 10 fine. I mean I don't even have to apply any fixes from the SRD!

I know I need to get another UPS backup power--the current battery has apparently expired. But I am still curious about this behavior of Windows.

A possible cause could be that the system has a very old legacy video card which I salvaged from a 12 year old Dell--and so maybe it doesn't get initialized or something upon power interruptions?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update 1**: One more clue: When the computer is idle, say for 10 minutes, the monitor starts to display 'Out of Range' and then monitors turns blank. But the computer always tuns the display on upon mouse movement subsequently. BTW, I don't think this is either 'Sleep' or Hibernate mode though.

**Update 2:** Possible clue from Lenovo itself: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht079429?tabName=Solutions

**Update 3:** I am almost certain, as I tried to say in the Comments below, the issue is related to the video adapter's drivers. And this gives more clue: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/262153-45-monitor-showing-range-windows-start-screen

Comment: When the volume shows as verify, do you let it verify? Verify makes me think the two drives are not in sync after the power outage. The verify process compares the disks for data integrity which can take time as the system is being used and verified in parallel?

Comment: Thanks. No, I have not done any Verify yet. I don't know if Lenovo's BIOS is asking me to verify the RAID via Windows or not? I also think that the video card was not fully compatible and I had to try really hard to find some 'drivers' for it--they are probably not fully compatible because I can't ever put the computer to Sleep/Hybernate.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286331

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am going to have to try another video card and see if I can duplicate the problem with that...